# lwuit and blackberry: access denied when deploying

Tags: blackberry, port, lwuit

I have made an application using lwuit svn in j2me cldc.  I am now working on 
lwuit + BlackBerry device.  When I build the project through the lwuit resource tools it creates three projects: desktop, MIDP, and BlackBerry. I use the BlackBerry project.

When I build and clean the project, it works fine.  However, when I deploy the project, it shows 'access denied'.  Where do I need to change the code or xml to run my app on a BlackBerry device?

```
blackberry-pre-run:
Copying 6 files to C:\Program Files\Research In Motion\BlackBerry JDE 6.0.0\simulator D:\WorkSpace\BB\RIM\nbproject\build-impl.xml:1052: Failed to copy D:\WorkSpace\BB\RIM\dist\Touch\BB_RIM.alx to C:\Program Files\Research In Motion\BlackBerry JDE
6.0.0\simulator\BB_RIM.alx due to java.io.FileNotFoundException C:\Program Files\Research In Motion\BlackBerry JDE
6.0.0\simulator\BB_RIM.alx (Access is denied) BUILD FAILED (total time: 54 seconds)
```

Answer (score 0):

[lwuit + blackberry how to build it show access denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6159944/lwuit-blackberry-how-to-build-it-show-access-denied/6167231#6167231)