# lwuit + blackberry how to build it show access denied

Tags: blackberry, lwuit

Hi every one please any one help me how to build blackberry lwuit svn generated hello world
example in blackberry simulator.

i have problem in building when i build blackberry rim app in netbeans it it build with out error but it show access denied i below mention error like

**D:\WorkSpace\NewProject\RIM\nbproject\build-impl.xml:1052: Failed to copy D:\WorkSpace\NewProject\RIM\dist\NewProject_RIM.debug to C:\Program Files\Research In Motion\BlackBerry JDE 6.0.0\simulator\NewProject_RIM.debug due to java.io.FileNotFoundException C:\Program Files\Research In Motion\BlackBerry JDE 6.0.0\simulator\NewProject_RIM.debug (Access is denied)
BUILD FAILED (total time: 40 seconds)**

i think it is problem of permission then i have no idea how can i do this pleas any one who know how to given permission blackberry device simulator i used os window 7

Comment: possible duplicate of [lwuit and blackberry: access denied when deploying](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6135601/lwuit-and-blackberry-access-denied-when-deploying)

Answer (score 3):

Installing to a different folder from program files might help.

What I did is spend roughly 30 minutes playing with the security tab in the "Settings" dialog when right clicking the folder in explorer.

You need to select your group/username and just grant all the permissions and apply them to all the subfolders.

Obviously there are security implications but since the toolchains are pretty ancient we need this for compatibility. The alternative is to "Run As Administrator" which is way worse.